# Get the current page url inside a hook for contao

Tags: tags, hook, contao

I am using the parseArticle hook for news module for my contao instance. I need to get the current page url inside this parseArticle hook. I had checked with the insert tags "{{env::url}}". But it's not working. It is simply displaying this text. Is there any way to use insert tags inside our hook?

If no, what should be done to get the page url inside that hook for contao?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the current URL via `\Environment::get('uri')`. This also includes the query string.

In general you can also "use insert tags" this way: `\Controller::replaceInsertTags('{{…}}')`, but this should never be necessary.

If you want the url to the reader page (without the news item in the URL), you can use

```php
global $objPage
$strRelativeUrl = $objPage->getFrontendUrl();
$strAbsoluteUrl = $objPage->getAbsoluteUrl();
```

Both of these function can take parameters to add to the URL. See [PageModel.php#L1013](https://github.com/contao/core-bundle/blob/4.4.7/src/Resources/contao/models/PageModel.php#L1013) for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  \Controller::replaceInsertTags('{{…}}')  worked for me.

Comment: Yes, but you should never need that ;). Always use the direct approach, not the insert tags.

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
\Environment::get('url');
```

Found on https://www.marcosimbuerger.ch/tech-blog/contao-environment-klasse-mit-beispielen.html